# is it possible to forward multiple ports to an http router with Traefik?

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

I have this simple Traefik 2 setup in the docker-compose.yml file of my container, which works.

```
labels: # traefik v2
    - "traefik.http.routers.airt.rule=HostRegexp(`airt.localhost`, `{subdomain:[a-z]+}.airt.localhost`)"
    - "traefik.http.routers.airt.service=airt" #assign to a specific service in order to have multiple services on the same host
    - "traefik.http.services.airt.loadbalancer.server.port=88"
    - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
```

The container runs a Nginx server which listens on port 88, and Traefik makes that accessible at `airt.localhost`.
Now, I'd like to also forward the Vite server port (defaults to 5173), so that requests to `airt.localhost:5173` can be forwarded to the Vite server inside the container.

I tried like this, but it doesn't work:

```
labels: # traefik v2
    - "traefik.http.routers.airt.rule=HostRegexp(`airt.localhost`, `{subdomain:[a-z]+}.airt.localhost`)"
    - "traefik.http.routers.airt.service=airt" #assign to a specific service in order to have multiple services on the same host
    - "traefik.http.services.airt.loadbalancer.server.port=88"
    
    - "traefik.tcp.routers.airt-vite.rule=HostSNI(`*`)" # the wildcard is required for non-tls, this is the only supported rule
    - "traefik.tcp.routers.airt.service=airt-vite"
    - "traefik.tcp.services.airt-vite.loadbalancer.server.port=5173"
    
    - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
```

I think that this tcp rule matches everything and prevents the http rule to work

```
traefik.tcp.routers.airt-vite.rule=HostSNI(`*`)
```

I tried to change the rule to `` HostSNI(`*:5173`) `` but that's not a valid rule.

Can this be done?

---

**UPDATE**: while the use case I propose in the question might still be useful to others, I found a workaround to my problem.
I could set the correct hostname for the links generated by Vite, while keeping it listening to all endpoint IPs, simply using the server.hmr.host directive, in addition to the server.host directive, in the vite.config.js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you can utilize multiple entrypoints that are on different ports.

Docs: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/entrypoints/
The image on that site explains it pretty well.